What size resistor do I need to limit current to 50A from a battery?
I am trying to limit the current flow from a 12 V 275 Ah battery to 50 A.
What size resistor do I need?
I need to limit the current to no more than 50 A to a lithium-ion battery spot welder.
The welder has a specific limit of 45 Ah. My battery is a 12 V 275 Ah car battery. It says the battery cannot exceed 45 Ah. If it exceeds 45 Ah I need to use a current limiting method or it will cause damage.
Yes it is for spot welding lithium-ion batteries.

"Limiting current" is not a good description of what resistors do. Maybe you could explain why you want to limit the current, and maybe you could say what you hope will happen when the "load" on your battery demands more than 50A, and maybe then, somebody can give you some suggestions.

ok ty sorry im new

please edit your question ... add a link to the welder documentation ... do not write a comment

Please take the [tour] and read "[ask]" and other pages of the [help] to learn how this site works.

The units you're throwing around don't make sense and it sounds like you might be either trying to do something that's impossible or worrying about something that's not a problem but let me explain: Ah (amp-hours) is a measure of battery capacity, A (amps) is a measure of current, which in this case is both consumed by the load and provided by the battery; saying "the welder has a specific limit of 45 Ah is non-sensical since loads do not care about the capacity of a battery. E.g. you can plug your phone into a tiny power bank with a capacity of 0.5 Ah or you can plug it into a giant "battery generator" with a capacity of 1000 Ah and it will operate exactly the same.
If the battery's datasheet or manual states that it cannot exceed a 45 A discharge rate and the welder requires more current than this, you are out of luck*. There is no way to limit current to the input of a device below what it is expecting and still have it operate properly. A resistor will just lower the voltage supplied to the welder until it malfunctions (while wasting energy in the process). This would be like putting a clamp on your car's fuel line in order to get better gas mileage.
If the current draw of the welder is 45 A and you are worried that the battery will force more current than that through it, then there is no problem. The battery just maintains a constant voltage (subject to normal voltage sag with loading and usage) across its terminals and the attached loads draw as much current as they need.
If you are worried that the welder will malfunction and draw more than its nameplate consumption of 45 A, then you need a fuse to disconnect it. Providing the full datasheets or manuals where you got these numbers would go a long way to helping us give you a definitive answer.
*Depending on how the welder operates, if the excessive current draw is only in short pulses, it is possible that a large capacitor could allow you to use it with this battery but that is hypothetical.

what is happening is the welder has 1 to 99 settings  1 has too much amperage it is the lowest setting and the instructions say 45 ah with a new batteryso i am trying to lower the amperage to use the settings at setting 1 it melts the nickel strip in 1/2 sec is there anything i can do to make the amp from battery limited to 45amps

the paperwork says it uses 5 mos tubes on the board if that helps capable of 400a ea in parallel as soon as you touch the leads to nickel strip it melts on setting 1 and it recommends 1 to 12 with the thickness im using 12 melts the strip and leaves it glowing past the melted part

A 0.24 ohm resistor rated at 600W would limit any 12V source to 50A.
But I'm not sure that's what the application calls for- you might want to request clarification from the welder supplier of the recommended circuit with your type of battery. If the purpose is to protect against failure of (say) MOSFETs in  the welder circuit, a fuse might be more appropriate. If the purpose is to prevent failure of the MOSFETs you might need something like a resistor but it might only have to be rated 600W for low duty cycle pulses.

A 0.24 Ohm resistor would draw approximately 50A from a 12V source if it were the only load. But, when most people (OP included) say "limit current," they want to limit the current through some other device (e.g., OP's spot welder.) Not only that, but often, they hope to somehow limit the current through the device without affecting the voltage seen by the device—a goal that is not realistic unless the current limiting can be achieved by activating some feature of the device itself.

@SolomonSlow I think OP is talking about some hobbyist type open board spot welder controller that just pulses a bunch of paralleled MOSFETs from a lead-acid battery.  The current is not controlled in such a device.

So, Yeah. An 0.24 Ohm resistor in series with the battery and the welder would guarantee that the battery never supplies more than 50A. It also would guarantee that the welder never would dissipate more than 150W—a mere one quarter of the power that the OP might have imagined. (The welder would dissipate even less power if its effective resistance did not, by coincidence, exactly equal the 0.24 Ohms of the dropping resistor.) I have no way of knowing whether 150W at 6V, or fewer Watts at some other voltage would meet OP's needs, so I'll be dropping out of this particular conversation.
